Use of transitive closure in proof of NC hierarchy collapse
Im looking at the proof of $NC^{i} = NC^{i+1} \implies NC = NC^i,\,i\geq 1$ in page 10 of the following article: https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Reports/TR-1986-001.pdf


I understand the general idea consists in creating a family of uniform circuits of depth $O(log^{i+1}n)$ from a circuit of depth $O(log^{i+2}n)$, please correct me if im wrong. However, I lose track of whats going on when it mentions that transitive closure is in $NC^2$, I don't understand the use of this problem in this proof, and again, maybe thats because im missing the bigger picture.

The answer by Mic is correct.  If you're not comfortable thinking of this in terms of Transitive Closure, instead use the fact that NL is in NC^2.  In NL, it is easy to determine the depth of each gate in a uniform family of circuits.  Thus, by the assumption that NC^{k+1} is equal to NC^k, there is an NC^k circuit family that takes x as input, and outputs a sequence of j=O(log n) circuits C_1, ... C_j, where each C_i is a subcircuit of our original circuit (of depth log^{k+2}n), corresponding to the i'th "slice" of depth log^{k+1}n.  That is, C_1 is the slice of the original circuit closest to the inputs, and the outputs of C_1 feed into the gates of C_2, etc.  By assumption, each of the C_i's (of depth log^{k+1}) can be replaced by uniform circuits of depth O(log^k n).  Gluing these circuits together gives a circuit of depth O(log^{k+1}n) ... which by assumption gives a language in NC^k.

The issue may be that the uniform circuit description is not leveled, you just see gates and wires. But using TC, you can compute a level number for every gate.

So basically when we divide the bigger circuit we get a circuit mess and this is allowing us to order it into the corresponding levels? In that case I still cant visualize the whole process involving the use of TC.
